# How can i make them all inline ? Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, woocommerce

Im trying to make each of them inline can someone help ?!

[image]

```html
<div class="atc_nsv"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <ul>
    <li><img class="ad lazyloaded" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_credit_score_black_24dp_256x256_crop_center_cf161a99-1910-4fbc-b74c-1967ee85df8e_200x.png?v=1637010126" style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_credit_score_black_24dp_256x256_crop_center_cf161a99-1910-4fbc-b74c-1967ee85df8e_200x.png?v=1637010126">Niet
      tevreden? 100% geld terug!</li>
    <li><img class="ad lazyloaded" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/Ontwerp_zonder_titel_21_200x.png?v=1637531197" style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/Ontwerp_zonder_titel_21_200x.png?v=1637531197">30
      dagen retourtermijn</li>
    <li><img class="ad lazyloaded" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_local_shipping_black_24dp_200x.png?v=1637009702" style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_local_shipping_black_24dp_200x.png?v=1637009702">Gratis
      verzending vanaf €20</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ul li{
display:inline-block;
} Try this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/9gfw30m8/3/

Comment: Hi my friend its woocommerce i want each one to be in line not all on same line !

Comment: @DeathNote what do you mean by inline?

Answer (score 0):

The html markup you've posted makes icons inline with descriptions.
It seems that something else affects the icons on the page that you take this code from.

```html
<div class="atc_nsv"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<ul>
        <li><img class="ad lazyloaded"
                data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_credit_score_black_24dp_256x256_crop_center_cf161a99-1910-4fbc-b74c-1967ee85df8e_200x.png?v=1637010126"
                style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;"
                src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_credit_score_black_24dp_256x256_crop_center_cf161a99-1910-4fbc-b74c-1967ee85df8e_200x.png?v=1637010126">Niet
            tevreden? 100% geld terug!</li>
        <li><img class="ad lazyloaded"
                data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/Ontwerp_zonder_titel_21_200x.png?v=1637531197"
                style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;"
                src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/Ontwerp_zonder_titel_21_200x.png?v=1637531197">30
            dagen retourtermijn</li>
        <li><img class="ad lazyloaded"
                data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_local_shipping_black_24dp_200x.png?v=1637009702"
                style="width:20px; margin-right:10px;"
                src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/5882/6972/files/baseline_local_shipping_black_24dp_200x.png?v=1637009702">Gratis
            verzending vanaf €20</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply! Im trying to put those icons and text on my woocommerce product page on woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button but its impossible !

Comment: Hi, you will need to share more context. Something that surrounds this piece of HTML has styles that make your items look wrong. Without seeing a container of this block with its styles here, it is impossible to clarify what is wrong.

Comment: https://rudrastyh.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/woocommerce-before-and-after-add-to-cart-hooks.png I want to add my text at "woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button" hook via functions.php